# How can I enable API request and MongoDB access only for the app server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are working on an app whose Front-end has been decoupled from the back end.

We have 2 project packages. The first project package acts as the front-end for the app and interacts with the 2nd package which acts as the back-end via API.

Front-end is built with:

- React
- Redux

Back-end is built with:

- ExpressJS
- MongoDB

We have deployed the app successfully on the AWS EC2 instance but I am doubtful about the security inbound measure we have applied for the packages. Both the packages are deployed on the same ec2 instance.

The front end of the app can be accessed with https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080. Under the security group, under inbound rules, I added the source as anywhere for port 8080 under the custom TCP rule.

I did the same for port 3000 reserved for the back-end API server and port 27017 reserved for MongoDB.

What I actually wanna do is only let the front-end package running on port 8080 talk to the API server and the API server in turn talks to MongoDB.

I do not want everyone to have access to the backend server and MongoDB except for the front-end app server.

Note that I have already used the JWT token to secure the API. This one is to add an extra layer of security.

How can I limit the access to only the Front-end app server?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Are both the project packages on same EC2 instance or different?

Comment: @error2007s It's on the same ec2 instance. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for pointing out. Added to the question

Comment: So everyone will not be able to access the backend server and Mongodb if you block the ports to just your IP address instead of opening them up to all.

Comment: My IP meaning the IP of the PC on which I am developing the app or the IP of AWS instance on the cloud?

Comment: IP of your internet connection

Comment: @error2007s
I restricted it to IP of my internet connection. But then my front-end can only interact with backend (express:3000 and mongodb:27017) if I request the app from my IP (or to be more precise from my PC). API request from the front-end stops working if people who aren't on the same network or same IP.

Comment: Keep 8080 open to all and 3000 27017 just to your internet IP

Comment: I did the same. 8080 is open to all. But I restricted 3000 27017 to my IP. So people can access the front-end but API request gets blocked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117226/discussion-between-rahul-house-javascript-and-error2007s).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, are you accessing your MongoDB directly from the frontend? I hope no...

So you should configure firewall on your server (`firewalld` or `iptables`) to block Mongo and all other internal ports from access from web.

Comment: This is good information, but AWS provides Security Groups at the network layer to handle this sort of thing, which is easier to use in a scalable cloud environment than configuring the software firewall on each server.

Comment: @AndreaKorinski
Nope. My frontend interacts with the API's built with express and MongoDB. Front-end has no clue what tech stack was used to build the API routes.

Comment: Also if I do not change the source for the ports 3000 and 27017 to anywhere (0.0.0.0/0), my front-end (8080) won't be able to access the API server.